# Header with memory size definitions

Tags: c++, c, size, header-files, c-preprocessor

Is there standard C/C++ header with definitions of byte, kilobyte, megabyte, ... ?
I dont want to make own defines. It's dirty in my opinion.

Example:

```
if (size > MEGABYTE)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Why in the world would you need it in the first place?  These things are not platform dependent...

Comment: There isn't. However some people agreed on calling `1024*1024` a `Mega` and `1000*1000` a `Megabyte`.

Comment: @alk Never heard of this convention before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: A ISO C++ standard header would define a Megabyte as 1.000.000 bytes, per ISO/IEC 80000-13. Also, per the C++ standard, that would not necessarily mean one million octets. Is that really what you intended?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, there are no such standard definitions. Probably because the added value would be very small.

You often see things like:

```
#define KB(x)   ((size_t) (x) << 10)
#define MB(x)   ((size_t) (x) << 20)
```

This uses left-shifting to express the operation *x* * 2<sup>10</sup> which is the same as *x* * 1,024, and the same for 2<sup>20</sup> which is 1,024 * 1,024 i.e. 1,048,576. This "exploits" the fact the classic definitions of kilobyte, megabyte and so on use powers of two, in computing.

The cast to `size_t` is good since these are sizes, and we want to have them readily usable as arguments to e.g. `malloc()`.

Using the above, it becomes pretty practical to use these in code:

```
unsigned char big_buffer[MB(1)];
```

or
    if( statbuf.st_size >= KB(8) )
    {
      printf("file is 8 KB (or larger)\n");
    }

but you could of course just use them to make further defines:

```
#define MEGABYTE MB(1)
```

Comment: Ok. I did my own define `#define MEGABYTE 1048576`. But your answer is pretty cool.

Comment: Note this is megabyte to byte. If you want byte to megabyte, you do `x >> 20`

Answer (score 17):

As other answers pointed out, there is not. A nice solution in C++11 is to use user-defined literals:

```
constexpr std::size_t operator""_kB(unsigned long long v) {
  return 1024u * v;
}

std::size_t some_size = 15_kB;
```

Comment: Even better, I like the idea of combining this with the C++ ratio templates used by std::chrono.  That way, all 'size' units have their own type with implicit conversion between them.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. But why you don't make them by your own :

```
const unsigned long BYTE     = 1;
const unsigned long KILOBYTE = 1024;
const unsigned long MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
const unsigned long GIGABYTE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

and also

```
const unsigned long long TERABYTE = 1024ULL * 1024 * 1024 *1024;
```

[Read more...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)

Comment: I would really suggest `size_t` as the type for sizes. Because it's a type for sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it adds much, but I quite like this form:

```cpp
#define KILOBYTES * 1024UL
#define MEGABYTES * 1048576
#define GIGABYTES * 1073741824UL
```

Which you can use like

```cpp
    if (size > 10 MEGABYTES) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean programming domain traditional `kilo = 1024`, then no.

If you mean SI unit standard `kilo = 1000`, then you can (a bit awkardly) use some that are defined in the C++ [ratio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) header.

```
#include <ratio>
constexpr auto two_kilo = std::kilo::num * 2;
```

I guess strictly you should account for both the numerator `std::kilo::num` **and** the denominator `std::kilo::den`, but absent a complete overhaul of scientific terminology, the denominator is going to be 1 for `std::deca` up, whereas the numerator will be 1 for `std::deci` down